# What video game is shown at 11:31 mark of Raycevick's "Guns, Gorillas, Gaming"?

Tags: game-identification

At [11:31 mark of Raycevick's video *Guns, Gorillas, Gaming*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y-_vgvEkkXQ&feature=youtu.be&t=11m31s) there's a footage of Japanese/Chinese/Korean-themed airship approaching a giant pair of stone hands, followed by a cut to a weird-looking humanoid skeleton being reconstructed.

[image]

What video game is that? Is this a cutscene from a released game, an art/story trailer for an abandoware, or a teaser for an in-development title?

Comment: Based on [this article](https://www.kotaku.com.au/2017/06/what-beyond-good-evil-2-is-now-and-what-its-creators-dream-it-can-be/), it appears to be 2017 concept art for the game *Beyond Good & Evil 2*. However, after researching the game, it's hard to tell if that is really it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's Beyond Good & Evil 2, as Wondercricket originally thought. It can be seen [here in a gameplay demo at E3](https://youtu.be/kjrzemJvUCU?t=976) at 16:16.

Comment: You have my +1. I was looking for the video that had that scene, but you beat me to it